# Is it possible to send gps location on an android device with a phone call?

Tags: java, android, gps, phone-call

Is is possible to send your gps location with your phone call when calling someone? Just wondering this to know is it possible to do this so if another android user is calling, then the other phone could transfer the current position (or situation, like "at work" or "at home",...) to the phone being called. That way, the incoming call could be announced as "Girlfriend calling from work".

Comment: you would need to implement a callback Method wich gets invoked when you call someone. In this callback method you would write your current position in a database (position, time, who you called). The call reciever could access this entry in his/her callback method when she recieves the call and show it on the display in a seperate Activity. The names "from work" had to be mapped to coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would certainly be possible with Voice Over IP, which actively uses data. Alternatively, it could also be done with a Carrier that uses a separate radio signal for data and voice. AT&T 3G/4G, Sprint 4G and Verizon 4G at least. However, it would be a debugging nightmare, as it would require the user to not be on a roaming network and to be in the appropriate coverage area for the dual radios to work.

An alternative would be to send the information over SMS prior to the call, so that they happen near seamlessly. This approach, however, would be traffic and device dependent. And there would be no guarantee that the SMS would get there before or even after the call. So, what you are asking for IS possible, but difficult to implement. It would be interesting to say the least.

Hope this helps,
FuzzicalLogic

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: No, it's impossible. At least, it would be carrier dependent.

I think the only way to achieve something similar is a second communication channel (such as a short message, email or similar things) sending this information ahead.

Answer (score 0):

At best, you would need to do this on a seperate "channel" from the call. I.e. you can NOT send data with a phone call. You *might* be able to run an http call that would pass the data to a server where the receiving call can retrieve the data from (using a custom app), or perhaps pushed using Android Push service.